# No primary or single public constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jwt

When I fire  refreshtoken api on postman I got this type of error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single public
> constructor found for interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
> and no default constructor found either

Here all the details of my filterclass and controller

jwtrefresh.kt:

```
package com.main.jwtrefresh.filter

import com.main.jwtrefresh.service.UuserService
import com.main.jwtrefresh.util.JwtRefreshTokenUtil
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
import java.io.IOException
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils


@Component
class JwtRefreshFilterUser : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jwtRefreshTokenUtil: JwtRefreshTokenUtil

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var uuserService: UuserService

    @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain,
    ) {
        try {
            val jwtToken: String? = extractJwtFromRequest(request)
            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwtToken) && jwtRefreshTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken)) {
                val userDetails: UserDetails = User(jwtRefreshTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken), "",
                    ArrayList())
                val usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities
                )
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

            } else {
                println("Cannot set the Security Context")
            }
        } catch (ex: ExpiredJwtException) {
            val isRefreshToken = request.getHeader("isRefreshToken")
            val requestURL = request.requestURL.toString()
            if (isRefreshToken != null && isRefreshToken == "true" && requestURL.contains("refreshToken")) {
                allowRefreshToken(ex, request)
            } else
                request.setAttribute("Exception", ex)
        } catch (ex: BadCredentialsException) {
            request.setAttribute("Exception", ex)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            println(ex)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    private fun allowRefreshToken(ex: ExpiredJwtException, request: HttpServletRequest) {
        val usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null)
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
        request.setAttribute("claims", ex.claims)

    }

    private fun extractJwtFromRequest(request: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        val bearerToken: String = request.getHeader("Authorization")
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

jwtcontroller.kt:

```
 @PostMapping("/refreshToken")
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun refreshToken(@ModelAttribute request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseEntity<*>? {
        val claims = request.getAttribute("claims") as DefaultClaims
        val expectedMap = getMapFromIoJsonwebtokenClaims(claims)
        val token: String = jwtRefreshTokenUtil.doGenerateRefreshToken(expectedMap, expectedMap["sub"].toString())
        return ResponseEntity(ResToken(token),HttpStatus.OK)
    }

    private fun getMapFromIoJsonwebtokenClaims(claims: DefaultClaims): Map<String, Any> {
        val expectedMap: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        for ((key, value) in claims) {
            expectedMap[key] = value
        }
        return expectedMap
    }
```

Comment: Remove `@ModelAttribute` annotation from controller method param.